# How to group characters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns. One is a groupname and the other contains values for the group as follows. The actual list is a lot longer

```
MyGroup   hello
MyGroup   goodbye
MyGroup   bonjour
YourGroup red
YourGroup blue
YourGroup green
```

I would like to create an output as follows

```
Mygroup<-c("hello","goodbye","bonjour")
YourGroup<-c("red","blue","green")
```

Can this be done using group in dplyr or is there another way to get the desired output?

Comment: Please read [how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nest` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_out <- data %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  nest()
```

You can access you groups doing:

```
data_out$data

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  words  
#  <fct>  
#1 hello  
#2 goodbye
#3 bonjour

#[[2]]
## A tibble: 3 x 1
#  words
#  <fct>
#1 red  
#2 blue 
#3 green
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function to split your data based on `groups` then use `unique` to get the list of unique strings or values

```
splited <- split(df, f = data$groups)
unique(splited$MyGroup$words)
unique(splited$YourGroup$words)

#> splited <- split(df, f = data$groups)
#> unique(splited$MyGroup$words)
#[1] hello   bonjour
#Levels: blue bonjour green hello red
#> unique(splited$YourGroup$words)
#[1] red   blue  green
#Levels: blue bonjour green hello red
```

Note: I replaced `goodbye` with another `hello` so that the results are clear, you can see only one `hello` is present.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(groups<-c('MyGroup', 'MyGroup', 'MyGroup', 'YourGroup', 'YourGroup', 'YourGroup'),
                 words<-c('hello', 'hello', 'bonjour', 'red', 'blue', 'green'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a simple `lapply`.

```
# Your data frame. 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' is used for the sake of making it
# more generic
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(rep("MyGroup", 3), rep("YourGroup", 3)),
    y = c("hello", "goodbye", "bonjour", "red", "blue", "green"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Makes a list for each group in column 1. The answer could be this line only
res <- lapply(unique(df[,1]), function(x) df[df[,1] == x, 2])
# Setting the names accordingly, for convenience
names(res) <- unique(df[,1])
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split :

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
MyGroup   hello
MyGroup   goodbye
MyGroup   bonjour
YourGroup red
YourGroup blue
YourGroup green")
```

**extract 2 vectors**

```
split(df1$V2,df1$V1)
# $MyGroup
# [1] "hello"   "goodbye" "bonjour"
# 
# $YourGroup
# [1] "red"   "blue"  "green"
```

**Assign to 2 variables in current environment**

```
list2env(split(df1$V2,df1$V1),envir=environment())

MyGroup
# [1] "hello"   "goodbye" "bonjour"

YourGroup
# [1] "red"   "blue"  "green"
```